# ¿Por qué tengo este error en mi select?

Tags: firebird

```
if (b.fecha >= :inicio as date and b.fecha <=:fin as date ) then
select  b.codigoproveedor,(SELECT a.nombreproveedor FROM proveedores a WHERE a.codigoproveedor = b.codigoproveedor),sum (b.cantidad)
FROM produccion b
group by 1
```

Y me sale este error alguien podria decirme cual es la manera correcta de escribirlo para que funciones:

> can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\WINDOWS\firebird.msg
>   not found. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -104. Token unknown -
>   line 1, column 1. if.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (b.fecha >= :inicio as date and b.fecha <=:fin as date ) then
    select  b.codigoproveedor
            ,(SELECT a.nombreproveedor FROM proveedores a WHERE a.codigoproveedor = b.codigoproveedor)
            ,sum (b.cantidad)
    FROM produccion b
    group by b.codigoproveedor,(SELECT a.nombreproveedor FROM proveedores a WHERE a.codigoproveedor = b.codigoproveedor)
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya resolvie ese problema graciasa  ti pero mira este que tengo